# MySQL: Select all movies that have sessions TODAY

Tags: php, mysql

I have web site for my local cinema and would like to enhance one of the queries on the home page.

I would like to select all movies that have sessions on today.

Two tables. One for movies, one for sessions.

The sessions table refers to the movie id as 'movie'. The sessions have a column called sessiontime. Movies also have their own start and end dates, representing the date they open and close at the cinema.

What I'd like to do is list all movies that have at least one session on today.

I tried, but kept getting as many results of each movie as there were sessions for today.

```
SELECT * FROM sessions, movies 
WHERE sessions.movie = movies.id 
AND movies.start <= '2014-07-02' AND movies.end >= '2014-07-02' 
AND sessions.sessiontime > '2014-07-02 00:00:01' 
AND sessions.sessiontime < '2014-07-02 23:59:59' 
ORDER BY movies.start ASC
```

Technically speaking we don't NEED to check the start and end date for the movie - as one would assume the admins for the cinema wouldn't put a session on for a movie that is no longer playing. But it's nice to check anyway. I primarily need to check that the movies in question have sessions on TODAY.

I'll be displaying the movies with sessions on today on the home page using a while in PHP.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kindest,

Scott

Comment: postgresql has date type which has current_date function and you can use - 1 or +1 to extend search , maybe mysql has something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply do, with your query

```
SELECT distinct movies.* FROM sessions, movies
```

I would also use a join instead of your syntax

```
from movies
inner join sessions on sessions.movie = movies.id
```

another way would be to use an exists clause, instead of a join, if you don't need anything in your resultset coming from the joined table

```
select m.*
from movies m
WHERE m.start <= '2014-07-02' AND m.end >= '2014-07-02' 
and exists (select null from sessions s
            where s.movie = m.id
            and s.sessiontime > '2014-07-02 00:00:01' 
            and s.sessiontime < '2014-07-02 23:59:59')
```

Comment: Just added the distinct movies.* to the start of my query as you suggested and it worked perfectly. I then tried it with the join an it worked also and looks like it performed the query slightly faster too. I am yet to try the exists clause. Many thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'm going to switch the query to modern JOIN syntax rather than commas; this doesn't make any difference in this case, I just find it much easier to read.

The actual fix is the GROUP BY, and the changed SELECT - you don't actually want to know what sessions there are, just what movies, so rather than `SELECT *`, you want to list the details of movies that you want (I've guessed a couple of columns). To avoid multiple rows, we GROUP BY all those columns we are selecting, meaning "for each distinct value of these columns, only output one row".

```
 SELECT movies.id, movies.name, movies.certificate
 FROM movies
 JOIN sessions
 ON sessions.movie = movies.id 
 WHERE movies.start <= '2014-07-02'
 AND movies.end >= '2014-07-02' 
 AND sessions.sessiontime > '2014-07-02 00:00:01' 
 AND sessions.sessiontime < '2014-07-02 23:59:59' 
 GROUP BY movies.id, movies.name, movies.certificate
 ORDER BY movies.start ASC
```

Comment: Hey there. Just wanted to thank you for your reply also. Your method also worked using the group by along with the join. Raphael's suggestion to use distinct also worked, which was a little less code than your suggestion. Is there any reason why we would use group by over distinct in the case of my query?

Comment: @Scott No, in this case the effect will be the same; GROUP BY is a bit more powerful, though, as you can add "aggregates" of the rows you've grouped together, such as the number of sessions with COUNT() or the first and last sessions with MIN() and MAX()

Comment: Ah, that's really interesting - regarding being able to run the COUNT() function on sessions within this single query. I could potentially see myself using that on this site in a future iteration. Many thanks :)